# Fitnesse slim test with SpringWirableFixture not terminating

Tags: spring, fitnesse

I'm creating a Fitnesse slim test (Decision Table). In order to run the test I need to start my Spring app. context. For that, I'm using a class that extends FixtureWirer. Starting the application context is not a problem, since the test completes successfully. In the page I can see that the test is complete and all the output values are compared. The problem is that the page with the final results never stops loading, but no exception is thrown. And that only happens when I use the FixtureWirer to start the application context, so I'm guessing the problem is related to that, but I haven't been able to figure it out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean the test doesn't stop as it is supposed to? If so, can you try to close the context

Comment: Thanks! This did the trick for me. My test just kept loading when running Fitnesse in the browser. Hitting the stop button didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

This may be because your Spring's shut down hook, is not being able to destroy beans which must
be blocked by any resource.

Can you check if there are any live threads after the execution of test that are blocked?

If there are any live threads left then Slim server would not terminate (SlimServer java process will not be killed).